# MySql - deleting rows from related tables

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have tables user, company and office with following relations:

```
company --> user
office --> user
office --> company
```

More verbally: companies and offices are users. A company may have offices.

The problem: How can I achieve following:

- When a user that is referenced by a company is deleted, also delete entry from company
- When a user that is referenced by an office is deleted, also delete entry from office
- When a company is deleted, also delete referenced user
- When an office is deleted, also delete referenced user
- When a company is deleted, also delete all referencing offices and corresponding entries from user table.

The last point is problematic, because it causes a loop: delete user (company) -> delete company -> delete office (can be multiple) -> delete user (office). It's not possible to have an on delete trigger on user table which causes deleting more rows from user table. Any solutions? Thanks!

EDIT: here's my (simplified) schema:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
  user_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id);

CREATE TABLE company (
  company_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  fk_company_user int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (company_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_company_user FOREIGN KEY (fk_company_user) REFERENCES 
    user (user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE office (
  office_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  fk_office_user int(11) NOT NULL,
  fk_office_company int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (office_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_office_company FOREIGN KEY (fk_office_company) REFERENCES
    company (company_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT fk_office_user` FOREIGN KEY (fk_office_user) REFERENCES
  user (user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: You had better show us your schema

Comment: Are you using a `ON DELETE CASCADE`? I think you have created a loop

Comment: Actually with cascades there is no loop, because same user cannot be an office and a company. Also, companies and offices are not supposed to be deleted directly, but instead corresponding user is deleted and cascading takes care of the rest. There's just one issue: If a company is deleted from user table, cascading deletes coresponding company and all its offices, BUT all offices that were deleted still have an entry in user table.